# Mule Studio - Adding Custom Templates

Tags: mule-studio

I'd like to add a custom template project to my Mule studio 3.5.0 install. So on creation of a new project users have the option of select "ABC Sample Project"

This [blog post](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/custom-project-templates-in-mule-ide/) suggests it is possible by placing a folder in the examples directory of the mule distribution. However I'd tried this and have failed to get it to work.

The post does not clearly indicate the pom.xml format so perhaps this is what I have done wrong. Also not sure if you need to restart, or have a new workspace for this to work. Using a maven archetype is most likely the recommended way to achieve templating but I'd prefer not to use maven.

Does anyone know if the information in this post is still applicable in 3.5.0 of Studio? Perhaps someone could clarify the pom.xml format for me? Is there an alternative mechanism?

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 0):

I've investigated further and have found a viable workaround/solution.

Seems Mule studio have created a extension-point which can be used to add custom mule examples. The process is as follows

1. Create a plugins folder in the \dropins folder
2. In this folder define a plugin as follows
3. Create a plugin folder.. i.e com.abc.mule.example
4. In the com.abc.mule.example folder create a plugin.xml file with the following contents

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
   <plugin id="com.abc.mule.examples"
      name="ABC Mule Example"
      version="1.0.0">
       <extension point="org.mule.tooling.muleExamples">
           <muleExample
                  description="ABC Example Project"
                  name="ABC Example Project"
                  path="examples/abc-example.zip">
               <targetServer serverVersion="3.4.0"/>
            </muleExample>
       </extension>
   </plugin>
   ```
5. Create an examples directory
6. Place a ZIP file called abc-example.zip with the sample project
7. Restart Mule Studio

Notes:

- You should update the plugin name, id, version
- You should change the mule example name, path & description to match what you want
- You can define an unbounded number of targetVersion elements to map the example to a particular version

Hope that helps someone. If anyone has an easier approach please post.

Thanks

Rich